# How to fill 2-dimensional array with floating points?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

Using Assemply
I need a simple code that fill a 2-dimensional array

**Update:**
That what I got so far. But still I have a problem in printing the array!

```
.data

arrayf: .word 600
msg1: .asciiz "Enter N: "
msg2: .asciiz " rows by "
msg3: .asciiz " values. Enter them: "
doneFill: .asciiz "Done with filling array\n"



.text

main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg1
syscall
li $v0, 5
syscall 
move $a1, $v0   # $a1 = N   
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $a1
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg2
syscall
move $a0, $a1   
addu $a0, $a0, 1
li $v0, 1
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg3
syscall


la $t1, arrayf
move $t0, $a1
add $t0, $t0, 1
mul $t0, $t0, $a1   # $t0 = N * (N+1) 

fill:   
li $v0, 6
syscall
swc1 $f0, 0($t1)
addi  $t1, $t1, 4
subi $t0, $t0, 1
bnez $t0, fill
li $v0, 4
la $a0, doneFill
syscall


la $t1, arrayf
print
lwc1 $f12, 0($t1)   
c.eq.s $f12, $f30
bc1t exit
li $v0, 2
syscall
add $t1, $t1, 4
j print
```

Comment: What architecture?  Single- or double-precision?  Please clarify what you're asking for, what you've done already, and the exact nature of the problem you're having.

Comment: it is single precision. The problem says that: 1- Get input N as the length of the array row. 2- each row has N+1 item. This make it an array[N][N+1]. 3- ask the user to fill the array. 4- print it

Comment: I forget to say that we use a MIPS Arch. Lang.

Comment: @2rk, you only did half of what I asked you to.  If this is a homework problem, tag it appropriately.  Homework problems aren't disallowed here, but you'll have to show us a lot more of your work.

Comment: @Carl I believe that this is the only info. I have about the problem. It is enough to make a meaningful question, isn't it?

Comment: @2rk, absolutely not.  Write some code.  Then when you have a problem come back here and ask about it.  We are *not* going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was in the print procedure. The condition to branch to exit was wrong.

**Thanks @blackbear & @Carl for spending your time trying to help me :)**

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 loops, one for columns and one for rows. Given `array[a][b]` the offset of `array[x][y]` is `x + y*a`

Comment: Thanks but this wasn't helpful.Please read the above comments

Comment: @2rk: I can't do your code, mine is just a suggestion. If you're already coding but having troubles post your problem here, we'll help you. ;) PS: @Carl is right

Comment: @blackbear I'm about to fix it :D . Give me a minute